# How much time do you spend networking with colleagues vs actually getting work done?

Tags: work-environment, politics, networking

I just joined my first industry job, around 8 months back, after my PhD.

I have a very busy schedule at my work, and try to be as efficient as possible. On top of that I go to networking events, have a side-project (business) as well a hobby or two.

If I have to get all of these done, I have very little time to chit-chat and schmooze at work. I work 7 days a week. I notice that others spend a lot of time gossiping, laughing around, getting lunch etc etc..

I get a lot done, but I am wondering if not socializing at work is going to kill my chances of promotion, because of politics etc?

Any advice? Should I set aside some time to socialize and carefully pick who to socialize with?

Comment: The headline version of the question is a survey, and not a good fit for SE. The last-line version is probably too much of an individual-cases question to be a good fit either. I don't think we can do much more than tell you to do what makes sense in your situation, remembering that situations change.

Comment: I guess I am looking for best-practice suggestions from people who have a very busy schedule, and how much they socialize at work... Not sure what you mean by "too much of an individual-case question".. Most questions here are very specific to an individual/situation.

Comment: If you work 7 days a week as a PhD holder, get the hell out of that industry. It's not healthy.

Comment: I dont mean I work 7 days a week on my day-to-day job. My day-to-day job is 9-5ish, 5 days a week. I work on my side-projects, early mornings & evenings (during weekdays) and all day on the weekends.

Comment: @alpha_989 most questions that are too specific to an individual/situation get closed...

Comment: So you do more work, while others are conversing and you worry about not being promoted ? You the more efficient worker ?

Comment: @ИвоНедев 1. Actually I dont think promotions are all about the most efficient person. Personality, politics, knowing the right people, all play a role, sometimes more than your own achievements.

2. I am more efficient in terms of "work done/time", but that doesnt mean that other dont get a lot done as well. I found that others spend a lot more time at work than me to get the same stuff done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spend less time worrying about what others are up to and more in making that critical career start, socialise to your hearts content once you have shown your professionalism and put in some solid work. You just got there.